# How can I re-use a custom dialog in the custom action sequence?

Tags: dialog, installshield

I am using a Basic MSI project in Installshield 2012 Spring. I created a custom dialog in the Dialogs section. This custom dialog is simple. It contains no buttons and 1 line of text that tells the user to Please Wait. I want this to be used in 3 areas of our installer where we have total silence that makes it appear like the installer is doing nothing or crashed.

I inserted the dialog into the custom action sequence list and set up an event where it will return to the installer when a property is set to FALSE. In another custom action I set a property to false. I tested the behavior and it is working fine.

Now onto the problem. I cannot find out how to re-use this dialog later on in the custom action sequence. I've tried using installscript examples I've found of sdShowAnyDialog, EnableWindow, EzDefineDialog, and WaitOnDialog and I cannot get any of them to show my dialog. Most of the time nothing pops up, but in one case, I was able to get a dialog to show using sdShowAnyDialog, but it ended up showing a totally different dialog or said that it couldn't create a dialog.

If there is an easier way to do what I want that doesn't involve installscript or duplicating the dialog in the Dialogs section, that would be awesome. I don't mind using installscript either, but I find that there isn't very good documentation on how to properly do this and when I try examples they never seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

In Basic MSI UI, the following methods can show a dialog:

- An entry in the appropriate sequence (typically the [InstallUISequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372039.aspx)) referencing the name of the dialog. This is how InstallWelcome and InstallProgress are shown.
- A [control event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368036.aspx) on a control of another dialog. There are three variants of this:

  - A [NewDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370533.aspx) event that "navigates" to an adjacent dialog, replacing the current one with the selected one (see the Next and Back buttons on most dialogs for examples),
  - A [SpawnDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371863.aspx) event that shows a child dialog or dialog sequence, or
  - A [SpawnWaitDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371864.aspx) event that shows a temporary dialog until a condition changes.

  Note that an [EndDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368362.aspx) event is required to terminate each sequence of subsequence of dialogs, but not the SpawnWaitDialog case. Note that some uses of SpawnWaitDialog have been problematic, but those mostly seem related to Costing, not custom waiting scenarios.

If I'm understanding your scenario correctly, I suspect the SpawnWaitDialog event approach may work best for you, but note that it is easy to [accidentally prevent the SpawnWaitDialog from showing a second time](http://www.robertdickau.com/msi_tips.html#spawn).

Comment: At various points during my install, I'm switching between InstallShield's dialogs and Forms that I've created in C#. These are typically the locations where I need the Please Wait dialog to show. And because of this transition, there really isn't a button click that happens that would give it a chance to spawn the dialog. I'd also rather not create the dialog in the C# Forms project if I don't have to.

Comment: @Brundle: I would suggest not using UI from another source. It's hard to guarantee it will parent correctly, and depending on how it is shown, it can lead to focus problems. That said, if you're running it from a control event, the next event could spawn the dialog...if that's not already too late.